# Flutter link geo: pero con algún parámetro que muestre algún label cuando abra el mapa

Tags: flutter

Actualmente tengo una app en playstore, que tiene base de datos de equipos con sus coordenadas.
Uno busca un equipo y la app muestra las coordenadas y si se hace tap, el sistema lanza url con `url_launcher: ^6.1.2`

```
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher
```

Todo va bien; ejecuto esta función:

```
  static Future<void> openMap(double lat, double lng) async {
    Uri url = Uri.parse('geo:$lat,$lng?q=$lat,$lng');
    await launchUrl(url);
 }
```

Este función  abre el mapa y efectivamente la app de mapas abre el marcador en el punto deseado.

Ahora necesito ir un paso más: ¿hay alguna propiedad que le pueda pasar en url para que cuando abra el mapa también muestre un label del objetivo deseado?

Mostrar el nombre del equipo en algún lugar del mapa.

Pasarlo algo así:

```
Uri url = Uri.parse('geo:$lat,$lng?q=$lat,$lng**&label=$equipoName**');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación de Google https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents#kotlin_10
es posible hacerlo de la siguiente forma:

```kotlin
// Display a label at the location of Google's Sydney office
val gmmIntentUri =
  Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=-33.8666,151.1957(Google+Sydney)")
val mapIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri)
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps")
startActivity(mapIntent)
```

Pasando ese código Kotlin a Dart, quedaría así:

```dart
static Future<void> openMap(double lat, double lng, String label) async {
    Uri url = Uri.parse('geo:$lat,$lng?q=$lat,$lng($label)');
    await launchUrl(url);
 }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias @diegoveloper.
Probe tal cual la recomendación.
Si me funciona, al abrir google maps si me muestra el label pero solo antes de iniciar ruta, para lo que necesito si me sirve, gracias.

NOTA: tal cual como me lo pasaste me dejo de funcionar con WAZE, Asi que tuve que modificar a esto.
Uri url = Uri.parse('geo:$lat,$lng?q=$lat,$lng($label)');

En el waze no funciona el label. Pero ya tengo resuelto lo que quería hacer